# Abelian and non-Abelian holonomies

Tags: terminology, gauge-theory, yang-mills

I read the article [Geometric Manipulation of Trapped Ions for Quantum Computation](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/292/5522/1695), and it mentioned “Abelian and non-Abelian geometric operations (holonomies)”. I know what is holonomy, and what is Abelian, but I didn't understand what are Abelian/non-Abelian holonomies.

I tried reading the references and searching Google, and found articles about those (non) Abelian holonomies, but with no explanations of what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "non-Abelian holonomy" is the holonomy of a principal connection with the group of the principal bundle being non-Abelian. (In more physics-y parlance, it's the Wilson lines of a non-Abelian gauge theory)